# Getting text content of a div element excluding its children

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code and I need to `console.log` only Shipping.
I tried a few methods but can't seem to get it to work.
I tried selecting first its children and printing out the `textContent` of its parent - no go. I could delete its children and print out what's left but I can't do that.

Any suggestions?

```
<div class="accordion shadowed-box shipping collapsed summary">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
    Shipping
        <div id="shippingTooltip" class="form-field-tooltip cvnship-tip" role="tooltip">
          <span class="tooltip">
            <div class="tooltip-content" data-layout="small tooltip-cvn">
              <div id="cart-checkout-shipping-tooltip" class="html-slot-container">
                <p>We ship UPS, FedEx and/or USPS Priority Mail.<br>  
                  <a class="dialogify" data-dlg-options="{&quot;height&quot;:200}" href="https://www.payless.com/customer-service/ordering-and-shipping/cs-ordering-shipping-schedule.html" title="shipping information">Learn more about our shipping methods and prices.</a>
                </p>    
              </div> 
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>
      <a href="javascript:app.checkout.editShipping();" id="section-header-note-sa" class="section-header-note" style="display: inline;">Edit</a>
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
var accordionChildren = document.querySelector('.accordion.shadowed-box.shipping>fieldset>legend *');//selects the first child
var accordionTitle = accordionChildren.parentElement;
var text = accordionTitle.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

I want to get Shipping but instead I get still all the text contents of the legend element.

Comment: Can you edit your post to add what output do you expect?

Comment: thanks just edited it... I explained what I did let me know if thats enough or if you would prefer me putting the js code

Comment: Yes go ahead and add the expected output of the `console.log` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access Text nodes by iterating over the child nodes (or access the intended node directly) of the accordionTitle variable.

```
let textNode = accordionTitle.childNodes[0],
    text = textNode.textContent;

console.log(text);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text

Answer (score 2):

You just need to find the `TextNode` child from all of the elements children, you do this by iterating over all of the `childNodes` and when the node type matches TextNode, return its `textContext`.

For a jQuery based solution on how to pick the TextNode child of an element see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) - but my example shows how to do it in vanilla ES (with a for loop over childNodes):

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onlyTextContent', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  get: function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if(this.childNodes[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        return this.childNodes[i].textContent.trim();
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log(
    document.getElementById('legend1').onlyTextContent
  );
});
```

```html
<div class="accordion shadowed-box shipping collapsed summary">
  <fieldset>
    <legend id="legend1">
    Shipping
        <div id="shippingTooltip" class="form-field-tooltip cvnship-tip" role="tooltip">
          <span class="tooltip">
            <div class="tooltip-content" data-layout="small tooltip-cvn">
              <div id="cart-checkout-shipping-tooltip" class="html-slot-container">
                <p>We ship UPS, FedEx and/or USPS Priority Mail.<br>  
                  <a class="dialogify" data-dlg-options="{&quot;height&quot;:200}" href="https://www.payless.com/customer-service/ordering-and-shipping/cs-ordering-shipping-schedule.html" title="shipping information">Learn more about our shipping methods and prices.</a>
                </p>    
              </div> 
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>
      <a href="javascript:app.checkout.editShipping();" id="section-header-note-sa" class="section-header-note" style="display: inline;">Edit</a>
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the contents of the `<legend>` tag as a string and then use a regular expression to remove the HTML tags and their content inside. Like this:

```
let legends = document.querySelector('.accordion.shadowed-box.shipping>fieldset>legend');
let title = legends.innerHTML.replace(/<.*/s, '');
// title = "Shipping"
```

The regular expression matches the first `<` character and everything that follows. So we replace that match with an empty string `''`.